# MongoDB $text search and external data filtering for injections

Tags: mongodb, security, code-injection, javascript-injection

Site data - is MongoDB collection. Search by site work with indexed $text $search by this collection. Do I need filter external data for MongoDB $text search or is no way to make some injections for code like:

```
db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: $_GET['search'] } } )
```

?

And need just replace html special chars on page return in this case.

Comment: Can you show a sample document and explain the expected result clearly?

Comment: Doc example from articles collection: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("583c2f7bfa46340720331a44"), "Article" :  "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout."  }`. Result - site search by articles.

Comment: add:\ (string) $_GET['search']